# Get Jquery $.post contents inside CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I need to download all text and images from a SSL secure website. I've done that bit successfully using CURL, however in it there are other text and images which get populated with a click on a link and that link calls JQuery's `$.post` request.

How to get contents through Jquery `$.post` inside CURL?

Comment: You should try executing the POST request using CURL as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do this manually, because cURL is not a browser, it doesn't run JavaScript. It can only do exactly what you have instructed it to do, perform a GET here, a POST there, etc.

You'd have to inspect the source code for each site yourself and add special instructions in your code that will perform requests that otherwise would have been done with `$.post()` and friends when run in a regular browser.

Comment: +1 for not loling and for answering with a straight face (sic)

Comment: +1 for the same purpose as  TigOldBitties

Comment: I am thinking of extracting onclick contents and then add iframe using jquery and onload of iframe run that jquery scripts, but I am not sure about its usefulness? What do you think??

Comment: @user1915024 Well, that wouldn't be a cURL implementation anymore; simulating browsers could be done with something like Selenium though.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the web page, searching for $.post, $.get and $.ajax calls, extract the URLs and parameters, and perform new curl queries. But in this way you will have only the http responses and if the server returns json, which is interpreted by JavaScript, you won't know how to interpret it.

So instead of downloading the page via curl, try downloading it via a headless browser, such as [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), which can execute JS code and save the result after all JavaScript is applied (it can intercept every http call so you can save the images as they are downloaded)

Comment: I am thinking of extracting onclick contents and then add iframe using jquery and onload of iframe run that jquery scripts, but I am not sure about its usefulness? What do you think??